# Morphing objects

Tags: shape-keys

Is it possible to morph an object from one mesh to another? I joined them into one big mesh and I want to morph them. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here is your answer to the previous post that you deleted:
https://youtu.be/PacjgROvohU

NOTE: I pressed <kbd>I</kbd> on the value slider before hitting it up to 1 then, realizing my mistake I moved the slider up to 1 and pressed <kbd>I</kbd> again to fix this.

### Steps:

1. Create the Sphere.
2. Add the *Shrink Wrap* modifier and select the cube as the object.
3. Click *Apply as Shape*.
4. Delete the cube.
5. Go to the *Data* Tab in the properties pane on the left.
6. Select the *Shrinkwrap* key and hit <kbd>I</kbd> on the slider with the *0* value.
7. In the timeline go to the time you want to end the morph on.
8. Increase the Value to '1' and hit <kbd>I</kbd> on it.
9. If you want to go from the cube to the sphere go to the Animation Layout.
10. Hit select the two rows of orange dots on the dope sheet and hit <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd>,<kbd>1</kbd>. This reverses the animation so now the animation goes from the cube to the sphere instead of the other way.

### NOTE: After step 10 make sure the timeline in the bottom is set accordingly.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry but I deleted that question because this was what I wanted to do in more detail.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged as if the link goes down then so does the answer. Please include the main steps of the answer within the answer body itself.

Comment: That's all right [bunnybot5555](http://blender.stackexchange.com/users/32399/bunnybot5555)
Also I have added the steps in case of a dead link

Comment: When I do this my cube is smaller than my sphere. Also how can I make the material change as well? I want the whole thing to change.